# Error during initialization of JVM

Tags: java, c++, qt, jvm

I realize this is a question that has already been asked by a few people but their answers did not fix my problem.

I'm currently trying to make a QT application and I have some code written in Java that I'd like to use, so I decided to implement the JNI into my application.

I use the following code to initalize the VM:

```
    JNIEnv* SokoSolver::createVM(JavaVM **JVM){
    JNIEnv* Env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options;

    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    args.options = &options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    int returnValue = JNI_CreateJavaVM(JVM, (void**)&Env, &args);
    if(returnValue < 0 || !Env){
        cout << "Unable to launch JVM, Return Value: " << returnValue << endl;
    }

    return Env;
}
```

However whenever my code is run I get an error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries.

I'm using the x86 version of the JVM.lib/JVM.dll, along with the relevant header files. As per the other answers I have changed the path variable in Windows to start with:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin; 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\bin\server;
```

But when I run my code I still get the exact same errors. Is there any other solutions to this problem? Does it have anything to do with:

```
options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with the class path. the class path influences where java types are searched, not native libraries. I know this does not really solve the problem, but as a workaround, you could try making the main application a java application and then use native code, instead of the other way around and using native code to start a java vm.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a problem with jdk installed on your system.
Just reinstall jdk 8u92 and add the same path in environment path in your system.